# Concept resolve to the unexpected function template when using std::make_signed_t

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Consider the following snippet

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
concept unsigned_integral = std::is_integral_v<T> &&std::is_unsigned_v<T>;

template <unsigned_integral T>
auto test(T) -> std::make_signed_t<T>; //(1)
template <typename T>
auto test(T) -> int; //(2)

int sandbox() {
  test(1u); // Call to (1) as expected
  test(1.0); // Expected to call (2), compilers choose (1) and fail to compile
}
```

MSVC 14.26, GCC-10, and Clang-10 all failed to compile this, so I suppose the standard makes this an invalid code, so should this be considered an oversight from the standard? because using SFINAE, the code is compiled as expected.

SFINAE version (this only works with the `double` case, because there will be ambiguity for the `unsigned int` case, but that doesn't affect the question I'm asking)

```cpp
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<unsigned_integral<T>>>
auto test(T) -> std::make_signed_t<T>;
```

edit: apparently, this does not relate to trailing return types, so I have changed the title to the appropriate one.

Comment: What's your equivalent SFINAE version? Because that may very well be the intricate point here

Comment: The compilers don't choose (1), they merely consider it and, while doing that, substitue `double` into `std::make_unsigned_t` (which for some reason is not SFINAE-friendly).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat but then it should work as SFINAE since if the first consideration fails, the next candidate should be considered, which is not the case

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I just added the SFINAE version

Comment: @UyHà SFINAE doesn't catch all errors. It only works for errors in the so-called *immediate context*, other errors will still abort the compilation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is CWG 2369 (unfortunately not on a public list despite having been submitted years ago). I'll just copy the main text here:

> The specification of template argument deduction in 13.9.2 [temp.deduct] paragraph 5 specifies the order of processing as:
>
> 1. substitute explicitly-specified template arguments throughout the template parameter list and type;
> 2. deduce template arguments from the resulting function signature;
> 3. check that non-dependent parameters can be initialized from their arguments;
> 4. substitute deduced template arguments into the template parameter list and particularly into any needed default arguments to form a complete template argument list;;
> 5. substitute resulting template arguments throughout the type;
> 6. check that the associated constraints are satisfied;
> 7. check that remaining parameters can be initialized from their arguments.
>
> This ordering yields unexpected differences between concept and SFINAE implementations. For example:
>
> ```
> template <typename T>
> struct static_assert_integral {
>   static_assert(std::is_integral_v<T>);
>   using type = T;
> };
>
> struct fun {
>   template <typename T,
>     typename Requires = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>>
>     typename static_assert_integral<T>::type
>   operator()(T) {}
> };
> ```
>
> Here the substitution ordering guarantees are leveraged to prevent `static_assert_integral<T>` from being instantiated when the constraints are not satisfied. As a result, the following assertion holds:
>
> ```
> static_assert(!std::is_invocable_v<fun, float>);
> ```
>
> A version of this code written using constraints unexpectedly behaves differently:
>
> ```
> struct fun {
>   template <typename T>
>     requires std::is_integral_v<T>
>   typename static_assert_integral<T>::type
>   operator()(T) {}
> };
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> struct fun {
>   template <typename T>
>   typename static_assert_integral<T>::type
>   operator()(T) requires std::is_integral_v<T> {}
> };
>
> static_assert(!std::is_invocable_v<fun, float>); // error: static assertion failed: std::is_integral_v<T>
> ```
>
> Perhaps steps 5 and 6 should be interchanged.

This basically matches the example in OP. You think that your constraints are preventing the instantiation of `make_signed_t` (which requires an integral type), but actually it's substituted into before the constraints are checked.

The direction seems to be to change the order of steps above to [1, 2, 4, 6, 3, 5, 7], which would make the OP example valid (we would remove `(1)` from consideration once we fail the associated constraints before substituting into `make_signed_t`), and this would certainly be a defect against C++20. But it just hasn't happened yet.

Until then, your best bet might be to just make a SFINAE-friendly version of `make_signed`:

```
template <typename T> struct my_make_signed { };
template <std::integral T> struct my_make_signed<T> { using type = std::make_signed_t<T>; };
template <typename T> using my_make_signed_t = /* no typename necessary */ my_make_signed<T>::type;
```

Comment: Scarrying! the direction is to perform a first set of substitution, then constraint checking then another step of substitution... Even if it gets closer to the lexical order, it will be harder to think about. Why not just using the lexical order: substitution and constraint checking in the same step. That would make constraint location significant, but I suppose most of the coder expected this. (I expected this, the one who asked the question too and others who put comments at least)

Comment: @Oliv I think "check constraints, then do stuff" makes a lot more logical sense than any other alternative. The problem with lexical order is that a trailing requires clause is the only place you can put a constraint in some cases, and I wouldn't want those to have different rules - I really do mean those constraints to constrain!

Comment: That would be great for a theoretician if it was realizable. But some substitution must be performed before. So the solution that is proposed does not provide the ideal but it add complexity. More over you look at the comment above, there are extremely skilled poeple that were expecting that constraint and substitution were performed in one pass. A declaration is a semantical atom and no, there is no more logical sense in any alternative. Even in formal logic we use the left-right top-down order. I think the decision should target the less surprising option.

Comment: @Oliv I don't see how it adds complexity. It does the same steps in a different order.

Comment: According to what I read `template <integral T, class U = make_signed_t <T>> auto test (T)` would suffer the same problem because template substitution in the template head would be performed before constraint check. But the problem would be solved for `template <integral T> make_signed_t <T> test(T)`.

Comment: The complexity is that as a coder I will have to think about 3 passes: 1 substitution in the template head, 1 constraint checking then 1 substitution in the type. So to fix non SFINAE friendly transformation traits, I put them in the type, and to avoid troubles with parameter mapping in constraints  I would use SFINAE in the template head (I admit I never seen it). I would prefer to think that SFINAE tricks and constraints are same class citizen, so that I could follow this simple rule: what is on the right fulfill requirements that are on left.

Answer (score 6):

According to [[meta]](http://eel.is/c++draft/meta#trans.sign-sentence-5.), `make_signed` mandate that the template argument is an integral type:

> *Mandates*: T is an integral or enumeration type other than cv bool.

So `make_signed` is not SFINAE friendly.

Constraint fullfilment checks are performed after template argument substitution. Template argument substitution happens when establishing the set of overload candidates and constraint fullfilment check latter, when establishing which overload candidates are viable.

Taking your case as an exemple:

1. The compiler establish the set of overload candidate, constraint are not checked here. So what is going to be used by the compiler is equivalent to:

   ```
   template <class T>
   auto test(T) -> std::make_signed_t<T>; //(1)
   template <typename T>
   auto test(T) -> int; //(2)
   ```

The compiler deduce `T` to be `double`, it substitute `T` in `make_signed_t` => Error: substitution failure does not happen in the direct context of `test` declaration.

The compiler stop here, compilation does not reach the second step of selection of viable candidates where the constraint would have been checked.

Comment: Huh. I wonder what was wrong from checking both requirements and regular SFINAE in a single pass.

Comment: Would it be considered bad practice to solve the issue by writing a more "SFINAE friendly" [version](https://godbolt.org/z/cDwvoU) of `std::make_signed`?

Comment: this is surely surprising, I thought concept resolving mechanism would be similar to SFINAE but apparently not